# Visual Studio 2017 community/Professional - Live Unit Testing

Tags: visual-studio-2017, live-unit-tests

I'm looking for a extension/plugin to allow live unit testing in VS 2017 Community or Professional.

I understand that this feature is available on the enterprise version, however I wanted to see if anyone knows of any alternatives out there without having to upgrade to enterprise.

Any information on this would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried NCrunch? http://ncrunch.net

It’s a lot more mature than LUT, and includes the ability to do things like install grid nodes on other computers/ servers that allow you to spread the processing.